# Is there a way to reliably prevent CoreLocation-coordinates from being snapped to nearby roads?

Tags: ios, swift, gps, location

An iOS-app I've been working on requires accurate coordinates to record the location of a moving vehicle. While I've been able to get it to work fairly well in general, the data I get from the CoreLocation service seems to occasionally snap to nearby roads, which is something I'd very much like to prevent from happening.

Looking around a bit on this issue, I've mainly found suggestions regarding the ActivityType and DesiredAccuracy configured for the LocationManager, but setting those to 'OtherNavigation' and 'Best' respectively, as was suggested most often, hasn't seemed to do the trick so far. Other ActivityTypes that have been suggested (Fitness, Other) haven't seemed to have any effect either.

Is there any way to reliably make sure I get the actual coordinates, without them being 'corrected' and snapped to nearby roads?

An example:

I tracked my location with a different tool, giving me accurate GPS logs:
[image]

But the data I received in my app snapped to the road eventually:

[image]

The fact that the coordinates I received seem to be exactly on a straight line makes me think the GPS is accurate enough, but it's just being corrected towards the single road that Apple Maps shows for this location:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that the default activity type of `.other`, not `.otherNavigation` is most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- I've edited the question to include some of the other ActivityTypes I've tried. I did indeed try .other, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Are you seeing this behaviour in built up areas (cities) or in the open?  If you are in a city area with tall buildings then gps accuracy will be compromised

Comment: I'm seeing it in very open spaces -- I've added some images comparing the accurate GPS data I got from a different tool to the data my app receives.

Comment: Is the "other tool" an app on your phone or another gps device?

Comment: It was a different app (Overland-iOS), running simultaneously with my own app. (I also tried running them both separately, rebooting the phone in between, but that didn't seem to change anything.)

Comment: If the other app is getting different data then the problem is with the settings on your cllocationmanager, not the device. Perhaps show how you are setting up the location manager.

Comment: While gathering some relevant bits of code to add to the question I noticed I was using 2 separate instances of the CLLocationManager -- setting configurations for one, and reading data from the other. Cleaning that up a bit seems to have solved the issue. Thank you for your directions and your patience! I'll go ahead and add an answer to this post in case it might be of use to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out eventually. I had created an instance of CLLocationManager in my AppDelegate where I set up its different configuration-options, but I was taking my data from a different instance of CLLocationManager, created somewhere else. This instance was still using the default .other ActivityType. After configuring it to use .otherNavigation instead, the road-snapping behavior went away.